# GRUB doesn't start when legacy boot enabled, otherwise it starts but Debian bears errors and doesn't launch

Tags: boot, debian, multi-boot, grub

I have installed Debian next to Windows on my Dell XPS 15 9560, but it doesn't start properly.

First, Debian installer didn't detect the disk, unless I have switched my BIOS settings to:

1. Secure boot disabled

   [image: Secure boot menu]
2. Legacy options ROMs enabled

   [image: Legacy boot settings]
3. Legacy boot option

   [image: Boot sequence options]

What's interesting, in the bootloader menu, I have started Debian installer from UEFI, not legacy options, but without doing the 3 steps listed above, it didn't detect disks.

Now, when I have the 3 above settings like that, the only thing I see after booting my computer is black screen with a prompt (but nothing else).

But if I enter boot menu (F12>/kbd>) while seeing the Dell logo and select "Debian" (which is GRUB) from UEFI boot options, I get a WORKING GRUB, where I can run Debian. But this is not really convenient to click F12 every time when I boot my laptop.

There is also third option to boot. I can switch some settings from the 3 above to other state and then I can boot directly to GRUB without clicking F12, but starting Debian then bears the following errors:

[image: Debian errors]

So what I want to achieve is start GRUB without entering boot menu, and be able to start Debian from GRUB. I think it could be achieved by installing GRUB so that it could be seen in legacy boot mode or modifying the setting in the working GRUB to start Debian in some legacy mode. Am I right? And how could I do this?

UPDATE:

I have tried installing Debian from legacy, not UEFI options in boot menu and now the only thing that has changed is GRUB doesn't work in cases it worked. Instead, GRUB rescue shows up.

But I can easily restore the previous state, when it worked.

Comment: Simple question, MBR or GPT, answer that question and I have an answer to your question

Comment: @Ramhound It is GPT

Comment: Windows when installed on a HDD using the GPT scheme can only boot in UEFI mode.  So turning Legacy mode on will make it impossible to boot into Windows....

Comment: @Ramhound OK, so how can I make Debian boot in UEFI mode, instead of displaying these ACPI errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally made it work! I have changed SATA Operations Raid On to AHCI in BIOS. I have also run `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal` in Windows (as administrator) before changing SATA Operations and `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot` after. I don't know if this was necessary, but I have found that here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/696413/ubuntu-installer-cant-find-any-disk-on-dell-xps-13-9350.

Then I reinstalled Debian in UEFI mode ("Enable legacy options ROMs" checkbox not checked).